# Pip Fatal Error in launcher: Unable to create process when using ""

Tags: python, pip

I already fixed this, but I will post the question anyways and answer it so if there are other people having this issue they may find this.

I installed blender a while ago and did some stuff using python. I can't recall what exactly I did, it was for a school project. However, when I recently tried to use pip to install something I got the following message:
`Error in launcher: Unable to create process when using "path to python my blender folder"`

Even if you get this answer due to another situation my solution might still help you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. First I uninstalled Blender.
2. Then I uninstalled python and reinstalled the newest version.
3. I deleted every environment variable path I could find leading to an old python version.
4. In the Terminal I entered `where pip` and still got some paths leading to old python versions, I went to these locations and deleted every folder labeled with an old python version, in my case these locations were `C:\Python37`and `C:\Users\myusername\Appdata\Roaming\Python`

And that's it. After that pip worked as it should.